# Why does my Quickly app install in /usr/bin instead of /opt?

Tags: application-development, quickly

As I've finished my app for the App Showdown, I ran `quickly submitubuntu`, but I found that my app is installed inside `/usr/bin`. What? I need it at `/opt`! How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, Eliah! :P

Comment: FYI, you've got three questions in the same question.  Each question should generally be separate.

Comment: Yes please, could you modify this question so it's a single question and open separate ones for the others? Thanks!

Comment: Splitting questions... ;)

Comment: Done! Now you have two questions instead of one. Second one is http://askubuntu.com/questions/160561/removing-my-app-from-ubuntus-ppa

Comment: Could you give us some more information? What exactly makes you say that your package created with submitubuntu installs in `/usr/bin`? Do you have code or the package somewhere public so that we can have a look?

Comment: Uploading, please wait...

Comment: @DavidPlanella Just uploaded to lp:~espectalll123/+junk/virtuam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, after running `quickly package --verbose --extras` (which does essentially the same as `quickly submitubuntu` except for uploading to a PPA) it looks your package does not even build.

It looks to me as if it might be an issue with the source tree layout. You've ported your app to Quickly, but you might need to make it a bit more Quickly-compliant. For one, I spotted that the `virtuam` folder where Quickly expects to find the app code is missing. You sould create and move your code there, instead of having it in `virtuam_lib`.

I've also noticed that in `vui.py` you've got a hardcoded path: `os.chdir('/usr/share/virtuam/ui')`. In general, hardcoded paths are considered bad practice, as they make your app less portable. Have a look at how Quickly loads the `.ui` file by creating an example app with `quickly create ubuntu-application foo`.

In general, if you need more help with this, I'd recommend to use the [Ubuntu App Developers mailing list](http://developer.ubuntu.com/community/), or the [Quickly talk mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~quickly-talk) as yours is a very localized issue that will require more support and might not be useful to other Askubuntu users.

Comment: I've done that chdir because I've done a false project and, after following the clues, I didn't know how Quickly loads the media/ui files... :/

Comment: Run `quickly create ubuntu-application foo`, then have a look at the `foo_lib/Window.py`. The builder is loaded with the `get_builder` function from the helpers.py module. But as I say, rather than a question, this issue requires a conversation, so I'd recommend sending an e-mail either to the ubuntu-app-devel mailing list or the quickly-talk mailing list.