# Removing my app from Ubuntu's PPA

Tags: application-development, ppa

As I've sent my app to Ubuntu's PPA using `quickly submitubuntu` and its version was wrong (12.07... right is 0.1!)

Details of the app:

- Virtuam 0.1
- Developed with Quickly (Python/GTK+3)
- Uploaded (as I said) with `quickly submitubuntu`
- The app is NOT in MyApps or in Launchpad (I removed it from LP)

I say that it was sent to Ubuntu's PPA because I saw a message about it was pending of review in the terminal... maybe I'm wrong and I can finish without worring about that :/

Comment: Could you be more specific, so that we can actually help you? What and where from do you want to remove? Your app? Your PPA? From Launchpad? From MyApps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... it was sent to my PPA, so I think that I was wrong. Sorry!